# How can I find files that have changed between certain times?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have windows 7 box with cygwin installed. I have multiple folders with files, within a single root folder. I want to find the list of files that have a time stamp within a specific date time range.

Comment: My best effort is: ls -Rlt

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `find` command with the `-newerXY` option.

From [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

> -newerXY *reference*
>   Compares the timestamp of the current file with *reference*. The *reference* argument is normally the name of a file (and one of its timestamps is used for the comparison) but it may also be a string describing an absolute time. *X* and *Y* are placeholders for other letters, and these letters select which time belonging to how *reference* is used for the comparison.

The possible values for *X* and *Y* are as follows:

- a - last access time of current file or *reference*
- B - birth time of current file or *reference*
- c - last inode status change time of current file or *reference*
- m - last modification time of current file or *reference*
- t - *reference* is a string representing a timestamp (not valid for *X*)

*X* refers to the current file and *Y* to the *reference*, so you'll want to use 'm' for the first letter (current file's modification date) and 't' for the second (timestamp passed as a string). Example script:

```
find . -type f -newermt "2012-05-01" ! -newermt "2012-05-15"
```

This finds all files that were modified between 1 and 15 May 2012. The `!` (logical `NOT`) operator reverses the meaning of the argument following it - if `-newerXY` means "X is newer than Y", then `! -newerXY` means "X is older than Y".

---

An alternative option, since you're on Windows, is to use Powershell. The [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347686.aspx) cmdlet returns all files in a given folder (recursively, if desired), and the [`Where-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) cmdlet allows you to filter the output of other commands. Example script (assuming the directory you want to search is the current directory):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge "2012-05-01" -and $_.LastWriteTime -le "2012-05-15" -and !$_.PSIsContainer }
```

This returns all files modified between 1 and 15 May 2012. You can use `CreationTime` instead of `LastWriteTime` to check for file creation time instead. The `!$_.PSIsContainer` filter only returns files (`PSIsContainer` is true for folders, and the exclamation mark is again the logical `NOT` operator).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Far Manager](https://www.farmanager.com/), `Find File` with filter: [image]

Hit the filter button, an press `Insert` to insert new filter:[image]

Name the filter somehow, enter file mask, check `Date/Time`, select value `change`, uncheck `Relative` and enter the date/time ranges: [image]

Hit ok, and in the `Filters menu`, press `space` to select the filter (`+` should appear next to the filter): [image]

Press enter, and hit `Find`: [image]

Search results (in this example photos - mask `IMG_*.jpg` - date range for June 2022): [image]

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to find that files with GUI File Explorer.
Some examples:

```
datemodified:2015-02-18 08:00..2015-02-18 13:00
datemodified:>2015-02-18 08:00
datemodified:<2015-02-18 08:00
```

And some further reading:
[Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows),
[Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: We expect high quality answers here at `Superuser` which means answers should include ALL relevant information not just links to external resources.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried to be useful...